# PHP nested 'require_once' loop

Tags: php

I have a file index.php which contains below code:

```
<?php
require_once('A.php');
// OTHER CODES ...
```

and A.php contains:

```
<?php
require_once('B.php');
// OTHER CODES ...
```

and B.php contains:

```
<?php
require_once('A.php');
// OTHER CODES ...
```

When I load index.php, my codes execute correctly and no error occurs.
Now my question is:
Is this algorithm correct? In other words how many times require_once can be nested. Will these 'require_once' can be repeate infinitely. Is there any other alternative method for this purpose?
Thanks.

Comment: why are you doing this? Seems rather silly to me instead of just having a and b in same file?

Comment: B.php is a huge php class file and it's not good to combine A.php and B.php @user2267175

Comment: Best to avoid circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require_once`, contrary to `require` allow the inclusion of your files only once. So no problem should occur with your inclusions.

Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

As an alternative, you could read how PHP autoloading mechanism works : http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Thanks. Is this means that if I use `require` instead of `require_once`, I got error?

Comment: Yes, by using `require` A will load B, then B will call A, and again A will load B. It is not a real error (just a bad algorithm). By doing this, functions in A may also be declared twice for instance (which will trigger an error).